# Remote Access Service

Tags: remote-access, ip-address, remote-connection

I just want to know that can any class of ip(both public and private) can be used for establishing a remote access service like ssh, or is their their any limitation that public cannot access private and so on.

Comment: What do you mean by public / private IP? [this article](http://www.debianadmin.com/private-and-public-ip-addresses-explained.html) defines them and if this is what you mean then no, there shouldn't be any limitations from private>public, barring from the control of the private network. As for public>private, it would get a little tricky, as there would be a undefined routing process involved in between.

Comment: Ya, this is what i mean by public and private ip addresses. So is it possible for a computer with public ip address to connect to another computer with private ip address, vice-a-versa and so on?

Answer (score 4):

Private IP addresses, defined by [RFC 1918](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/technologies/tk648/tk361/tk438/technologies_white_paper09186a0080091cb9.html), are not routable on the public internet and therefore cannot communicate directly with public IP addresses.

However, if a private address space(s) reside behind a form of address translation such as [NAT or PAT](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/technologies/tk648/tk361/tk438/technologies_white_paper09186a0080091cb9.html), communication between inside local addresses, that are mapped to inside global addresses can communication with outside local and outside global addresses (not taking into account firewalls, IP filters, etc.).

[image]

Comment: I know about NAT, Since i m not able to connect from PC having public ip to PC having private ip i am in doubt or unclear about any limitation on using public and private ip addresses in case of any remote access service like SSH

Comment: If SSH(TCP 22) is open on a device with a private address and that device is mapped to a public address, any public address can communicate with said device. Additionally, any other devices with a private address, that are mapped to a public address can communicate to the originally mentioned device. Of course, there are variables to consider such as port forwarding and firewalls(mentioned above).

Comment: When connecting to a device outside of your private address space(s) the destination IP address will need to be public. Example for *nix: `ssh user@public.ip.address`

Comment: but i m not able to connect to public ip address from private one. public ip that i gave was 123.201.193.39, so the command was `ssh matrix@123.201.193.39` but it always waits for long time and says connection timed out. But i m able to connect to my private ip from public one. Also i am not able to connect to public ip with another public ip. In Short i m only able to connect private-to-private and private-to-public.

Comment: The 10,000 foot view; A public IP addresses can be accessed via the 'internet' if the source address is a public IP. Given that private IP addresses can be translated to a public IP address(es), any private IP address is capable of reaching a public IP address. As for your timeout, it's likely caused by the port being blocked or the destination isn't listening or port-forwarding correctly.

Comment: Here is a bit of reading that may provide more details on IP addressing basics [Cisco_IT_IP_Addressing_Best_Practices.pdf](http://www.cisco.com/web/about/ciscoitatwork/downloads/ciscoitatwork/pdf/Cisco_IT_IP_Addressing_Best_Practices.pdf).